# I am getting text IO wrapper returned on python every time I run the code

Tags: python

This is a snippet of some simple code I've been working on for a school project. However, I keep having this: `io.TextIOWrapper name='score.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'` returned every time. I can't find any solution to fix this so can anyone help me please? Thanks.

```
s=[]
p1details=["ash",""]
p2details=["lillie",""]
import random
p1details[1]=random.randint(1,100)
p2details[1]=random.randint(1,100)
if p1details[1]>p2details[1]:
    s.append(p1details)
elif p2details[1]>p1details[1]:
    s.append(p2details)
#with open("score.txt", 'r') as G:
 #   print(G.read())
with open('score.txt','w') as score:
    s.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
    score.writelines("%s\n" % place for place in s)
score.close()
leader=open("score.txt")
print(leader)
score.close
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: What is the code meant to do? On the last line you appear to be missing a pair of parentheses, but it's the wrong variable anyway.

Comment: That's caused by `print(leader)`. Are you trying to print the contents of the file there?

Comment: that is everything im getting. No traceback or anything. the code runs fine but it's returning this

Comment: yes i am trying to print it, does that not work?

Comment: first: you forgot `()` in last `close()`. Second: to print content of file you have to use `.read()` in `print(leader.read())`

Comment: oh yes, im fairly new to python and i wouldnt recognise these things, thanks. i just hadnt put read in print(leader)

Comment: Can you explain what the sorting and appending etc. are meant to do? I'm trying to refactor the code.

Answer (score 0):

To display content of file you have to `read()` it

```
leader = open("score.txt").read()
print(leader)
```

If you don't use `read()` then `leader` has only file's handler which you can use to read it later.

```
leader = open("score.txt")
print(leader.read())
```